# Is it possible to use method calls to member objects of an array? How?

Tags: objective-c

So, I am currently planning to develop a larger command line application in Objective-C. The application is supposed to read in a table in a file (essentially, experimental data of a varying number of experiments in columns); I want to represent each individual experiment (data in a column) by an object of one or a few class(es) - representing what the data stands for, and coming with methods to evaluate the data in the very experiment. Hope, so far this is clear.

What I am now wondering: adjacent experiments (columns) need to pass information from one to the other in order to allow one another to evaluate themselves. More concrete: background experiments must average each other, and then pass the average to the actual data (in between the background experiments) in order to background-correct data.

In other words: I will need a collection object that keeps track of all individual experiment objects, and that calls the respective evaluation methods of the data objects in a reasonable fashion; e.g., it would take care that the background objects first average themselves one after the other, and then transfer the information of their evaluation (averaged backgrounds) to the data objects in the next step, which would then use those values to evaluate themselves. Also, calibration data would need to be evaluated in a similar fashion, and passed on to the evaluation of the data - hope You get the idea.

So, what I now want to know:

1. To You experiences programmers: does my approach (using collection classes and controller objects, and making each individual experiment an object with methods to evaluate itself) sound at least somewhat reasonable?
2. If so: how would I go ahead to create those collection objects - and how can I call methods of the individual members in an array of objects (or what other collection class exists)? At the moment, I don't even have a clue how to call methods in such objects - which wouldn't have individual names; I could only imagine that those objects would be referenced by pointers stored in the array.

I am pretty novice - and I have to admit that this very project is quite a challenge to me; yet, if I can manage to find a sensible approach, it would help me understand this class of problems (I have another project that seems to ask for a very similar approach). A simple indication regarding what path to use - or a helpful term to search for and read up upon would be very helpful. So far, I haven't been able to find a good programming model in any of the texts I have read; but I might still be too inexperienced to even "see the light".

Comment: I'd highly recommend adding some code to this post. While you have _a lot of detail_, people can get lazy when they see a wall of text.

Comment: Hi, Kevin! Thanks for Your suggestion! I would - but I haven't written any code regarding this issue (yet), since I don't know how to approach it...

Comment: That's the other problem, I just realized that the question is a bit broad. It makes sense now, as you don't have any code to work from. (Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way)

Comment: Yeah, I see... probably was not the smartest idea to try to get a reply here... :-)